# Is this really a way to filter LFI?

Tags: php, lfi, local-file-inclusion

I'm not sure if this is a valid way how to filter LFI, because if you bypass `in_array` function you can include any file, for example `/etc/passwd`.

Is it possible to bypass `in_array` function?

```
<?php
$file = $_GET['file'];
$files = array("some", "files", "here");

if (in_array($file, $files, true)) {
   include('directory/' . $file);
   echo "In array \n";
} else {
   echo "Not in array \n";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good, the `in_array` methodology is valid, especially since you enabled strict matching.